# JPA does not seem to persist. Not reading newly inserted row from HSQLDB

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, hsqldb

*Updated the entire question*

I am able to read an existing row from a in-memory HSQLDB but not a newly inserted row. I am assuming JPA is persisting based on the log. I think I have a proper Spring transaction. 
The transaction log is this.

```
    DEBUG: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttribute
    Source - Adding transactional method 'test' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED
    ,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
    DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Creati
    ng new transaction with name [com.jpa.test.TestImpl.test]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,
    ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
    DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource - Creating new
     JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dataSource]
    DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Acquir
    ed Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@113c3db] for JDBC transaction
    DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Switch
    ing JDBC Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@113c3db] to manual commit
    TRACE: org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager
     - Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@560c0a] for
     key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource@1d2ecdc] to thr
    ead [http-nio-8080-exec-79]
    TRACE: org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager
     - Initializing transaction synchronization
    TRACE: org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor - Gett
    ing transaction for [com.jpa.test.TestImpl.test]
    INFO : jpa -  TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()true
    INFO : jpa - INMEMORY_DB [id=id, street=Street,  area=Area, state=State, country
    =LO, pin=1]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - Opened session at timestamp: 1440153
    1526
    TRACE: org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - Setting flush mode to: AUTO
    TRACE: org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - Setting cache mode to: NORMAL
    TRACE: org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager
     - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@896d58] for key
    [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@c0cde] to th
    read [http-nio-8080-exec-79]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue - ID unsaved-value strategy UNDE
    FINED
    TRACE: org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - Transient instan
    ce of: com.jpa.test.INMEMORY_DB
    TRACE: org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener - Saving transie
    nt instance
    DEBUG: org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identi
    fier: id, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.Assigned
    TRACE: org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - Saving [com.jpa.
    test.INMEMORY_DB#id]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Adding an EntityInsertAction for [
    com.jpa.test.INMEMORY_DB] object
    TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Adding insert with no non-nullable
    , transient entities: [EntityInsertAction[com.jpa.test.INMEMORY_DB#id]]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Adding resolved non-early insert a
    ction.
    TRACE: org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions - No unresolv
    ed entity inserts that depended on [[com.jpa.test.INMEMORY_DB#id]]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions - No entity i
    nsert actions have non-nullable, transient entity dependencies.
    TRACE: org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor - Comp
    leting transaction for [com.jpa.test.TestImpl.test]
    TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Trigge
    ring beforeCommit synchronization
    TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Trigge
    ring beforeCompletion synchronization
    TRACE: org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager
     - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@896d58] for ke
    y [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@c0cde] fro
    m thread [http-nio-8080-exec-79]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - Closing session
    TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl - Closing JDBC con
    tainer [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl@19b7baa]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Closing logica
    l connection
    TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Logical connec
    tion closed
    DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Initia
    ting transaction commit
    DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Commit
    ting JDBC transaction on Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@113c3db]
```

I have this entity.

```
package com.jpa.test;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "INMEMORY_DB")
public class INMEMORY_DB implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "STREET")
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "AREA")
    private String area;

    @Column(name = "STATE")
    private String state;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "PIN")
    private int pin;

    public INMEMORY_DB() {
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }


    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public INMEMORY_DB( String street,
                    String area,
                    String state,
                    String country,
                    int pin) {
        super();
        this.street = street;
        this.area = area;
        this.state = state;
        this.country = country;
        this.pin = pin;
    }




    public String getArea() {
        return area;
    }


    public void setArea(String area) {
        this.area = area;
    }


    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }


    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }


    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }


    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }


    public int getPin() {
        return pin;
    }


    public void setPin(int pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }


    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "INMEMORY_DB [id=" + id  + ", street="
                + street + ",  area="
                + area + ", state=" + state + ", country=" + country
                + ", pin=" + pin + "]";
    }

}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="testingSetup" >
<!--These two lines don't seem to be useful. They don't seem to help ? -->
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
<class>com.jpa.test.INMEMORY_DB</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

I couldn't spot the bug. The schema is this.

```
CREATE TABLE INMEMORY_DB(ID VARCHAR(5),STREET  VARCHAR(10),AREA VARCHAR(40),STATE VARCHAR(35),COUNTRY VARCHAR(2),PIN integer);
```

The relevant code that tries to persist and read the newly inserted row is this.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void test() {
    logger.info(" TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()"
    +  TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() );
    INMEMORY_DB a = new INMEMORY_DB();
    a.setId("id");
    a.setStreet("Street");
    a.setArea("Area");
    a.setState("State");
    a.setCountry("LO");
    a.setPin(1);
    logger.info( a.toString() );
    entityManager.persist( a );
}

@Transactional
public void getAddress(){
    logger.info("INMEMORY_DB:: "
            + entityManager.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + INMEMORY_DB.class.getName()).getSingleResult()
                .toString());   
    TypedQuery<INMEMORY_DB> query =
            entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM INMEMORY_DB c", INMEMORY_DB.class);
          List<INMEMORY_DB> results = query.getResultList();        
    for( INMEMORY_DB memdb : results){
        logger.info( memdb.toString() );
    }
}
```

These two lines seem to indicate it is persisted.

```
    TRACE: org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener - Saving transie
    nt instance
    DEBUG: org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identi
    fier: id, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.Assigned
    TRACE: org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - Saving [com.jpa.
    test.INMEMORY_DB#id]
```

*Update :*

This may also have something to do with the way I use the DB. It may be persisted but not visible ?

```
        <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>  

    <jd:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
      <jd:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
      <jd:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"/>
    </jd:embedded-database>
```

*Update :*

i just tried to persist to a MySql DB. It reads existing rows but doesn't add new rows. Can anyone understand the problem ?

*Update :*

The transaction manager was wrong. It works now. But Spring has too many layers that make it hard to track down seemingly simple bugs like this. I want to point that out.

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transact
ion as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$
HibernateConnectionHandle@952e9b]
```

Comment: Where is your DAO code for saving something. You say you are unable to save, and yet there is no relevant code which shows how you are actually doing it. Strange!!!

Comment: I think there appears to be a transaction but it isn't the right one. How ?

Comment: Did you noticed that you are using in-memory DB and not MySQL? Spring cant just magically migrate to MySQL from In-memory db.

Comment: Don't know what you are assuming here. This is solved. Did you have a solution before I updated it ?